# Python-Creating a table from non-numerical data lists

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am looking for a way to create a simple table given a set of 3 lists of text data, as well as a list of headers. Here's the rundown: I need 3 columns, and an indefinite number of rows, depending on the data source. I also prefer not to have to import anything, if there is a way to do it normally in Python. Alternatively, I'd be fine with using either pandas, matplotlib, or some combination thereof. Here is my code:

```
headers=["SCHEME","SERVER","PATH"]
schemes=[]
servers=[]
paths=[]
colLabels=['PATH','SERVER','SCHEME']
rowLabels=[]
def homework2(filename):
    """Opens a file, extracts URLs, parses them, and places them into table"""
    filedata=open(filename,"r")
    for url in filedata:
        lineurl=SimpleURL(url)
        schemes.append(lineurl.scheme())
        servers.append(lineurl.server())
        paths.append(lineurl.path())
```

This code reads a given text file, takes each line, and parses the URL into the scheme, server, and path. The three lists (and the headers) look like this:

```
['SCHEME', 'SERVER', 'PATH']
['http', 'https', 'https']
['google.com', 'twitter.com', 'github.com']
['/', '/pretend/me', '/asdflkjas/stuff']
```

And I'm looking to create this output, or something similar to

```
SCHEME        SERVER         PATH
http          https          https
google.com    twitter.com    github.com
/             /pretend/me    /asdflkjas/stuff
```

I've tried using a DataFrame and the table() function, but I wasn't able to make it work.

Comment: colLabels and rowLabels are both left over from one of my attempts. Also, I have a class called SimpleURLs that makes it easy to separate the parts of the URL.

Comment: It cannot be done using a module that would have to be installed on another computer.

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
import pandas

headers = ['SCHEME', 'SERVER', 'PATH']
scheme = ['http', 'https', 'https']
server = ['google.com', 'twitter.com', 'github.com']
path = ['/', '/pretend/me', '/asdflkjas/stuff']

data = {}

for i, header in enumerate(headers):
    data.update({header: [scheme[i], server[i], path[i]]})

df = pandas.DataFrame(data=data, columns=headers)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
       SCHEME       SERVER              PATH
0        http        https             https
1  google.com  twitter.com        github.com
2           /  /pretend/me  /asdflkjas/stuff
```

With `pandas`' `DataFrame` we can do this easily.

Just concatenate the headers and the data into a dictionary, with the headers being the keys and the lists of `scheme`,`server`, and `path` being the values.

Then just plugin to `pandas`' `DataFrame`!

**Note:**

If you would like to get the same output in fewer lines of code, you can rewrite the lines that concatenate the lists into a dictionary as a less clear, but equally functional, dictionary comprehension like this:

```
data = {header: [scheme[i], server[i], path[i]] for i, header in enumerate(headers)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. `column_width` is the max length of the elements in each column.

```
headers = ["SCHEME","SERVER","PATH"]
schemes = ['http', 'https', 'https']
servers = ['google.com', 'twitter.com', 'github.com']
paths = ['/', '/pretend/me', '/asdflkjas/stuff']

def show_URL(headers, schemes, servers, paths):
    column_width = [max(len(x) for x in row) for row in zip(headers, schemes, servers, paths)]
    for item in [headers, schemes, servers, paths]:
        str_printing = ""
        for index, val in enumerate(item):
            str_printing += "{:{}}".format(val, column_width[index] + 5 )
        print (str_printing)

show_URL(headers, schemes, servers, paths)
```

output:

```
SCHEME         SERVER          PATH                 
http           https           https                
google.com     twitter.com     github.com           
/              /pretend/me     /asdflkjas/stuff
```